# Solving a constrained vector system with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to replicate the pendulum DAE example in the Documentation Center ([example/ModelConstrainedSystemsAsDAEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/ModelConstrainedSystemsAsDAEs.html)) using Mathematica 9's vector support with NDSolve.

So far I have:

```
deqns = {m X''[t] == \[Lambda][t]-{0, m 9.81}};
constraints = {Norm[X[t]] == 1};
initialConditions = {X[0] == {1, 0}, X'[0] == {0, 1}};
params = {g -> 9.81, m -> 1, l -> 1};

pendulumSol = 
 First[NDSolve[{deqns, constraints, initialConditions} /. 
   params, {X, \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 15}, 
     Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]];
```

but am getting:

```
NDSolve::ndincd: "Initial conditions for derivatives of the 
                  function X[t] do not have consistent dimensions."
```

Is this an issue with NDSolve properly identifying the vector nature of the equations, or have I overlooked something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `deqns` is not quite right to begin with: where are the X[t] and -m g? But this is not the cause of the error message, however. I'm wondering how can MMA determine the dimentionality of Lamda?

Comment: I suppose I thought that Mathematica would assume Lambda would have the same dimensionality as X. (Obviously not the case?)

Comment: Lamda could be scalar or a vector from the way you write the equations. How can MMA tell?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to specify the dimension of X when you solve this kind of equations, mathematica can't just deduce it from the fact that `{0,9.81}` has dimension 2, however the behaviour of `NDSolve` is still quite curious, try with:

```
X[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]};
vec = {0, 9.81};
conditions1 = {Norm[X[t]]^2 == 1, X[0] == {1, 0}, X'[0] == {0, 1}};
conditions2 = {x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 == 1, x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 0, 
x1'[0] == 0, x2'[0] == 1};
deqns = X''[t] == \[Lambda][t] X[t] - vec;
sol = NDSolve[{deqns,conditions2}, {X[t], \[Lambda][t]}, {t, 0, 15}, 
      Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}];
```

If you use `conditions2` the output of `NDSolve` is what should be: plot it with `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[X[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 15}]` you'll see that it is what you expect from a pendulum, however with `conditions1`, which is substantially the same, the kernel crashes and mathematica gives no output.

Note that deqns is written using vectors (like `conditions1`) in both cases but doesn't make the system crash, I can't explain why this happens only with initial conditions or constraints.

EDIT:

```
conditions3={x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 == 1, X[0] == {1, 0}, X'[0] == {0, 1}};
conditions4={X[t].X[t] == 1, X[0] == {1, 0}, X'[0] == {0, 1}};
```

work as fine as `conditions2`, so the problem must be with the function `Norm`.

EDIT 2:

As asterix314 noted my first answer was essentialy a trick to avoid the use of `NDSolve` with symbolic vectors like X[t] since I think that this is in general a more robust approach: `NDSolve` presents many bugs when dealing with vectors, in the solution of this system we encounter two of them:

1) `NDSolve` can't handle equations with both symbolic vectors (like X[t]) and lists (like {0, 9.81}) this is because the expression is evaluated BEFORE `NDSolve` starts operating on it, for example: `X''[t]==X[t]+{a,b}` is immediately evaluated to `X''[t]=={X[t]+a,X[t]+b}`, only after the evaluation `NDSolve` looks at the initial conditions and realizes that X[t] is a vector.

Obviously now on the lhs we have a 2-dimensional vector while on the rhs we have a nested list, because X[t] is a vector itself. This triggers an error, to avoid it I usually define the constant vector in this way:

```
c[t_?NumericQ]:={a,b}
NDSolve[{X''[t]==X[t]+c[t],X[0]=={x01,x02},X'[0]=={x'01,x'02}},X,{t,0,10}]
```

Now this works, why? because mathematica doesn't know c[t] is a list until he tries to numerically evaluate it thanks to the conditional pattern `_?NumericQ` which checks its argument (maybe this is not the most efficient way to go, but it's the only thing that came to my mind).

2) If you try to solve the OP's equation with this trick you'll notice that `NDSolve` still issues the same error: I think it happens because of the 1-dimensional condition `Norm[X[t]]==1`, however I don't think there's a real solution for this: when using `NDSolve` with symbolic vectors all the initial conditions regarding them must be vectors, at least to my experience. It is a limit of `NDSolve` and this is why I suggest to define vectors as lists and then solving the equation like I proposed at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: But your answer does not use the vector capabilities of `NDSolve` -- X will be reduced to {x1, x2} before `NDSolve` sees them.

Comment: @asterix314 {x1,x2} is a vector, but I got your point, I think it has something to do with the vector {0, 9.81}: `X[t]-{0,9.81}` is evaluated to `{X[t], X[t]-9.81}` before the equation is solved, that is, before mma sees that X[t] is a vector.

Comment: I mean the solution will be for x1 and x2 as scalars, not for X as a vector. The question is how to solve for X in and of itself as a vector.

Comment: Yes, this is a known problem that happens when you add known constant constant vectors (which NDSolve treats as lists). I will edit my post with a workaround, however I think the solution I presented is the simplest one, after all in this case vectors are used just to simplify the notation.